# Where are Python file buffers stored?

Tags: python, file, io, operating-system, python-internals

Recently implemented a file format API and was wondering why the file size wasn't updating until `close()`. Did some searching and found that the content is written to a buffer until `close()` is called. I wanted to see if I could update the file size as the writes were being called, so I threw in a `flush()` call, but that did nothing unless `os.fsync()` was called.

For the API, speed is everything. Calling `flush()` with `os.fsync()` is slower because now disk writes are taking place. Turns out its nearly 2x slower, so using the buffer and waiting for `close()` is better. However, some of these files can get quite large and memory needs to be considered. For that reason I would've thought that clearing the buffer to disk would be best, until I noticed that a ~4GB buffer doesn't even appear in memory. I was monitoring the process that was writing the 4GB file and memory usage never increased; in face, overall memory never increased. Monitoring the disk shows writes occurring before `close()` is even called, yet the OS does not know the file size has increased.

So where does these buffers exist to store this information before writing to disk?

**Edit:**

Doing some more research I found the following:

- `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is 8192 bytes
- It appears CPython uses internal [buffers](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-protocol)

I'm not familiar with file i/o at this level, but I would guess that when the internal buffer is filled it is "transferred" to the operating system's buffer and then written to disk. However, even though it is written to disk, the operating system doesn't update its view of the file (i.e. its size/properties) until the stream is closed.

Comment: `flush()` flushes the Python buffer to the operating system. The operating system buffers data in the kernel before writing to the disk. But you shouldn't be able to detect that buffering, the file size should be updated in the kernel's inode.

Comment: @Barmar Those operating system buffers, do the hold the entire buffer until the stream is closed? That is to say, a Python buffer holds 8192 and dumps to an operating system buffer, does it in turn immediately dump to disk or does it keep stacking? If its the latter, shouldn't that be visible on the system in RAM usage?

Comment: They're completely independent of the Python buffers and streams.

Comment: They're normally written to disk as soon as possible, but the OS schedules them based on all the other processes writing to disk, disk head movement, etc.

Comment: When buffers are written to disk, the buffer isn't freed immediately, in case a process wants to read the same data. Managing kernel buffers is elaborate, since they're also shared with memory mapping. This is really a complex operating system design question.

Comment: @Barmar How are the "independent"? They are filled from the content initially put in the Py_Buffer objects, at least thats what the docs say. Regardless, memory is being consumed somewhere, but where? What hardware is the buffer using to store memory because it doesn't appear to be in RAM (at least not visibly).

Comment: Once Python writes its buffer to the kernel, the kernel doesn't know or care what Python does with the buffer or stream.

Comment: @Barmar If that were the case, why does a file size property not update until the stream/buffer is closed?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. `flush()` should be all you need.

Comment: @Barmar Which `close()` calls, but still, even if I `flush()` and refresh the file explorer, no properties update.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I just did `f = open("test.txt", "w")` `f.write("foobar")`. At this point the file size was still 0. Then I did `f.flush()` and the file size changed to 6.

Comment: I did this all in Terminal on a Mac, not using a graphical file explorer.